# Ion beam optics software

Tags: optics, resource-recommendations, software, accelerator-physics

I'm starting a new project that requires the simulation of a ion source test facility.  I don't have much knowledge of beam optics so I want to find a beam optics software that is easy to learn/use.  Can someone please recommend me one? It doesn't have to be free.

Answer (score 4):

I've used SIMION, http://simion.com/; I was designing electron guns, and simply needed to vary some parameters with cylindrical symmetry.

This was almost 15 years ago; it is a mature package. You can also look for free codes developed at the national labs. Depending upon your design requirements, you may need to invest considerable effort in developing your model(s) with the various codes.

Comment: SimIon remains a standard tool, so that would be a good place to start.